# Group By Linq resultset

Tags: c#, linq

Linq :

```cs
var data = groups
    .SelectMany(g => g.Warnings.Select(w => new { g.Category, Warnings = w }))
    .Where(d => d.Warnings.Type == "Drug to Drug Interaction")
    .Select(s => new Group(
        Category.GetFromTitle(s.Category.Title), 
        s.Warnings.ToEnumerable().ToReadOnlyCollection())
    );
```

I have a LINQ query which provide result like the below

Actual Output :

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Category1 | Warning1 |
| Category1 | Warning2 |
| Category2 | Warning3 |
| Category2 | Warning4 |

But I'm expecting the table like below where grouping with the category should happen

Expected Output :

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Category1 | Warning1 |
|  | Warning2 |
| Category2 | Warning3 |
|  | Warning4 |

I want the warning 1 and warning 2 should be displayed under the Category 1, and both warning 3 and warning 4 should be displayed under the category 2.

Group.cs :

```cs
partial class DataGridView
{
    private partial class Group
    {
        [GeneratedCode("Emis.Weaving", null)]
        public Group(
            Category category,
            ReadOnlyCollection<Common.Warnings.Mkb.Warning> warnings)
        {
            _category = category;
            _warnings = warnings;
        }

        private readonly Category _category;
        private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Common.Warnings.Mkb.Warning> _warnings;

        public Category Category
        {
            get { return _category; }
        }

        public ReadOnlyCollection<Common.Warnings.Mkb.Warning> Warnings
        {
            get { return _warnings; }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried multiple LINQ variety with different group but unable to get the desired output.

Comment: hmm.. you're expecting `Warning2` and `Warning4` to not have a category? or are you just talking about a Display\View consideration here?

Comment: yeah its about Display\view consideration i want warning 1 and warning 2 should be tagged under category1 and w3 , w4 should be tagged under category 2.

Comment: Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: I don't understand what `Warnings` type is here actually.  is it an `Observable` of some sort? you are doing `ToEnumerable()` on it after being flattened with `SelectMany`.  the `Select` to `Group` is still going to produce a record for every `Category` which was expanded with the flattening.   If it wasn't for that `ToEnumerable` I would expect a `.GroupBy` here before doing `Select` to `Group` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this refactor of your code,

```
var data = groups
    .Select(g => new Group(
        Category.GetFromTitle(g.Category.Title),
        g.Warnings
            .Where(WhereIsWarningType)
            .SelectMany(SelectWarningToEnumerable).ToReadOnlyCollection()))
    .Where(WhereGroupHasWarnings)
    .ToList();


bool WhereIsWarningType(Common.Warnings.Mkb.Warning w) => 
    w.Type.Equals("Drug to Drug Interaction");

IEnumerable<Common.Warnings.Mkb.Warning> SelectWarningToEnumerable(Common.Warnings.Mkb.Warning w) => 
    w.ToEnumerable();

bool WhereGroupHasWarnings(Group g) => g.Warnings.Any();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that following LINQ query would certainly help you to find the expected group by result set that you want.

```
var categoryWiseWarningList = (from cw in db.CategoryWarnings
                                         join w in db.Warnings
                                         on cw.warningId equals w.warningId
                                         join c in db.Categories
                                         on cw.categoryId equals c.categoryId
                                         select new CategoryWarningViewModel
                                         {
                                             Category= c,
                                             Warning = w
                                         });
```